# Is there a way to check if a file is tracked in p4api with C# using just the file path?

Tags: c#, p4api

I am using the p4api and want to check weather a File is tracked or not. Thing is I only have the full path and not the depot path.

```
FileSpec fs = new FileSpec(new DepotPath(filePath), VersionSpec.Head);
IList<FileSpec> lfs = new List<FileSpec>();
lfs.Add(fs);
Options options = new Options();
var a = _repository.GetFiles(lfs, options);
```

Comment: What you mean by files "being tracked"? The files that are [opened](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_opened.html) ? Or whether the files are part of workspace or being [ignored](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_ignores.html) ?

Comment: the files that are in my workspace, that I already added with mark for add. 
I want to check if a file is only local